# Storing dataframe in a sqlite database using Flask API

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

So I am fairly new to flask and I am currently trying to create a flask api for a project I am working on. However, there are a couple of issues I am facing.

So for my 1st issue, I can't get my dataframe from the 1st function to work in my second function. I am just wondering how I can get the `data_1` to work in the second function.

Code:

```
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlite3 as sql
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
   ...
   data_1 = ...
   #print(data_1.head(n=10))
   return "hello"
@app.route('/table1', methods=['GET'])
def store_table1_data_df():
  db_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'table1.db')
  engine = create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(db_path), echo=True)
  sqlite_connection = engine.connect()
  sqlite_table = 'table1'
  data_1.to_sql(sqlite_table,sqlite_connection, if_exists='append')
  sqlite_connection.close()
  return "table1"
```

For my second issue, is there a better way of storing a dataframe within flask api using sqlalchemy or sqlite3?

More context as to what kind of `data_1` is: `data_1` can only hold the past 15 days/records like from 6/15/2021-6/30/2021. However, tomorrow, if I fetch the newest `data_1` it will contain 6/16/2021-7/01/2021. How can I just append 07/01/2021 to the old `data_1` without creating duplicate records from 06/16/2021, creating two more functions, and an extra db file?

```
@app.route('/table1', methods=['GET'])
def store_table1_data_df():
  db_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'table1.db')
  engine = create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(db_path), echo=True)
  sqlite_connection = engine.connect()
  sqlite_table = 'table1'
  data_1.to_sql(sqlite_table,sqlite_connection, if_exists='append')
  sqlite_connection.close()
  return "table1"
@app.route('/table2', methods=['GET'])
def store_table2_data_df():
  db_path2 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'table2.db')
  engine2 = create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(db_path2), echo=True)
  sqlite_connection2 = engine2.connect()
  sqlite_table2 = 'table2'
  data_1.to_sql(sqlite_table2,sqlite_connection2, if_exists='append')
  sqlite_connection2.close()
  return "table2"
# What I probably have down below is not the correct way to solve this problem
@app.route('/table1', methods=['GET'])
   conn = sql.connect("table1.db")
   cur = conn.cursor()
   #cur.execute
   cur.execute("ATTACH 'table2.db' as 'table2' ")
   conn.commit()
   table_3 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT DISTINCT date, value FROM table1 UNION SELECT DISTINCT date, value from table2 ORDER BY date", conn)
   cur.execcute("SELECT DISTINCT date, value FROM table1 UNION SELECT DISTINCT date, value from table2 ORDER BY date")
   conn.commit()
   results3 = cur.fetchall()
   sqlite_table='table1'
   table_3.to_sql(sqlite_table, conn, if_exists='replace')
   cur.close()
   conn.close()
   return "work"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st problem. You may do either of these:

1. If the size of data-1 is small(than 200kb) you may use flask-session to store the data and access it across routes.
2. You create a function that returns data_1. Call that function in any route you want. Hint:

```
def getdata1(val1, val2):
    #calculation here
    return data_1
```

Just call this wherever you need data_1.

3. Store the data frame in a DB and fetch it.

For the second part, a simple for loop will work. Hint on that:

```
sql_table = ["Fetch your sql table here with the dataframe. Considering dates in one column"]
data_1 = ["Your dataframe"]
for i in data_1['Dates']:
    if i != sql_table['dates']:
        #insert this key:value pair in sql table
```

If your data frame and sql is getting loaded in order by date, even better. You just need to check the last elements of each.